# Asserting a Record while excluding specific properties - NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a record containing several properties.

I would like to assert properties of the record based on the type, not all using NUnit.

```
public record Employee(
       int id,
       string Name,
       double Salary
       ....
)
```

I can assert properties of the record individually using `Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(id))`

But would like to know if we can compare record to record excluding some properties of it based on type?
Like `Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(employeeRecord).And.<Types within employeerRecord for comparision>)`

Tried `Assert.That(result.ToString(), Is.EqualTo(employeeRecord.ToString()))`

However, in this case, we may not be able to compare the type of data, as all data gets converted to string.

In other words, Can I filter a record based on the type of data and then assert only specific fields within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
[Test]
public void AddMethodTest1()
{
    Record result= new Record() { id=1 , Name="name" ,Salary="salary"};
    Record employeeRecord = new Record() { id = 1, Name = "name", Salary = "salary" };
    Assert.AreEqual(new { result.Salary,result.Name }, new { employeeRecord.Salary,employeeRecord.Name });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in my record there were multiple properties, like 20+ and it was difficult to write each property numerous times. Hence, I've used `with` operator to make the properties I don't want to be null and compared record to record.

Comment: @buneShot Maybe the method 3 could help https://stacktuts.com/how-to-compare-two-objects-in-unit-test

Comment: Yes Jerry, implementing `EqualityComparer` was extra lines of code which might be too much for my requirements as of now.